# Flutter Grid View elements's cornerRadius not working

Tags: android, ios, flutter, google-maps-flutter

this is my issue:

I have a GridView.count with a List.generate as children.
Basically I have a grid of maps made with google_maps_flutter and I want to give each of them a corner radius but **it applies only to the last element of my list** , I've tried putting corner radius everywhere:

1. inside a box decoration wrapping my elements inside a container, various tries never worked.
2. wrapping in a clipRRect, still applies only for the last element.
3. giving to my custom widget Map a corner radius, still applies only for the last element.

I think it is a render problem, when I run my app on a physical device and not the simulator, it works well for every cell in android, but in iOS there is still the problem. please help.
[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4w0PV.png)

[start of the list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Eqme.png)

I want all the cells to have a border radius

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHGat.png)

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed us your code

Comment: Does the Mappa widget in code have some padding that might be interfering with the `ClipRRect`?

Comment: No there is no padding from the Mappa widget interfering, just checked

Answer (score 0):

Try using `clipBehavior`

```
ClipRRect{
  clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
  child: ...
}
```

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work, just tried.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Card(
  clipBehavior: ...,
  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
  ),
......
)
```

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work, just tried. Still it affects only the last map square